# 'Merging' Local Server and AD Accounts

Tags: pam, kerberos, sssd

I am investigating LDAP-bridge options, but have a hurdle to overcome: pre-existing local accounts.

There are a large number of *nix servers (hundreds) with local accounts on them formatted in all *lowercase* user IDs (example: poppyllama). The Active Directory domain I need to bridge to uses all *uppercase* user IDs (example: POPPYLLAMA).

So far I have used sssd, krb5, and pam_ldap to allow for AD authentication/external identity source, but I am not quite sure how I would be able to 'merge' the current *local* accounts and groups with the AD domain accounts and groups.

Any ideas? Does anyone have experience with anything like this?